# from ubuntu server 16.04 LTS to ubuntu server 18.04 LTS change of swap partition

Tags: boot, server, partitioning, swap

I recently changed from ubuntu 16 to 18 and i had set up ubuntu 16 with a swap partition of 8 GB but now i discovered that the new swap partitions are created with the use of a file and not with a specific partition of the disk.

what are the problems that i could face in the future?
is there way to update the position of my swap (that is still on a separate partition)? (or maybe during the installation of ubuntu 18 the system already did this job?)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel supports swap on a file, and swap as a partition. It will probably support both for the foreseeable future.

Furthermore, a swap space is not necessary for normal operation of the system, unless you are very limited in RAM. If you have more than 2GiB of RAM, you will be able to update and boot your system, even without any swap space. If kernel support should radically change in the future, you will thus be able to configure it at that time.

So for now: Don't worry.

To check what you use for swap, run

```
cat /proc/swaps
```

This will print swap spaces in use. If they're on file or a partition doesn't really matter.